# freetype-gl LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\freetype-gl.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, freetype

I have been struggeling for the past month to run the projects within the sample solution generated by cmake on the freetype-gl project..

https://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/

I am running Visual Studio 14, and when i try to build "ALL_BUILD" or any other project individually i get the same error:

> LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\freetype-gl.lib'

This is really frustrating me, i have located freetype-gl.lib in /windows/freetype/ and i have copied it over to /Debug/ but Visual Studio still "cannot open file".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcJie.png

The only thing i really noticed is the folder is windows locked read-only and i cannot remove the attribute from the folder... I have also been unsuccessfully with the attrib command in cmd.exe. PLEASE HELP >.<

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bits?

Answer (score 0):

You might to try with latest version at https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl

Answer (score 0):

here is how I go about working with libraries.

First, I add include and library directories to 'configuration properties->vc++ directories' and then in 'configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependecies' the name of the library file, in your case 'freetype.lib'.

hope it helps!